# Why an instance of class could be called?

Tags: python

When using plt.cm.Spectral in python, I got some confused.
After checking the type of ***plt.cm.Spectral***, I regard the var Spectral in module plt.cm as an instance of class LinearSegmentedColormap.
However, I also see that code ***colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))*** could be executed without error. Here is the point confusing me, why an instance of a class could be called, i.e. followed by parentheses with params inside?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python objects are callable if they implement [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__):

> `object.__call__(self[, args...])`
>
> Called when the instance is “called” as a function; if this method is defined, `x(arg1, arg2, ...)` is a shorthand for `x.__call__(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

`LinearSegmentedColormap` inherits from `Colormap` that implements `__call__`:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/colors.py#L433

This makes an instance of `LinearSegmentedColormap` callable.